# test - No provider for TranslateService

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I'm running some tests using the `ng test` command and I get the following error message:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[TranslateService -> TranslateService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateService!
```

The test is:

```
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TranslateTestingModule } from 'ngx-translate-testing';
import { CoreModule } from './core.module';

const ENGLISH_LANGUAGE = 'en';

describe('AppComponent', () => {

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let appComponent: AppComponent;

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    appComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        CoreModule,
        TranslateTestingModule
          .withTranslations(ENGLISH_LANGUAGE, require('assets/i18n/en.json'))
          .withDefaultLanguage(ENGLISH_LANGUAGE)
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    expect(appComponent).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should have as title', async(() => {
    appComponent.ngOnInit();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(appComponent.testTitle).toEqual('app');
    })
  }));

});
```

And the component is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  testTitle?: string;

  constructor(
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    private screenDeviceService: ScreenDeviceService
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    const subscription: Subscription = this.translateService.get('app.title').subscribe((text: string) => {
      this.afterLanguageResourcesLoaded();
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
  }

  private afterLanguageResourcesLoaded(): void {
    this.setAppMetaData();
  }

  private setAppMetaData(): void {
    this.screenDeviceService.setMetaData({
      title: this.translateService.instant('app.title'),
      description: this.translateService.instant('app.description')
    });
    this.testTitle = this.translateService.instant('app.title');
  }

}
```

I also tried importing the `BrowserModule` module:

```
imports: [
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
```

And I tried adding a `TranslateService` provider:

```
providers: [
  TranslateService
]
```

I finally tried having two member variables for the two services to be injected into the component constructor:

```
let translateService: TranslateService;
let screenDeviceService: ScreenDeviceService;
```

and providing them:

```
providers: [
  TranslateService,
  ScreenDeviceService
]
```

and getting them:

```
translateService = TestBed.get(TranslateService);
screenDeviceService = TestBed.get(ScreenDeviceService);
```

But nothing helped.

I'm under Angular `9.0.4`

UPDATE: I ended up using the real translate service instead of the mocked one and had to kill the test runner and type in again the `ng test` command for my source code to be considered.

Answer (score 33):

In your test spec.ts file you could add this type of import, with `forRoot()`:

```
TranslateModule.forRoot()
```

An example:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

This because you haven't to test the TranslateModule too.
This solution works to me.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't change anything to the error. As a side note, the TranslateModule needs to be mocked: https://dev.to/lados/how-to-fix-ngx-translate-error-when-running-tests-5ado

Comment: It does not have to be mocked, you can provide the `TranslateService`in your test

Comment: All right, I removed the mocked service and used the application one. But the error remains the same. It feels like the `TranslateService` is not created in the Angular context and thus is no where to be found to be injected.

Answer (score 1):

In your test file:

1. Add an import:
   `import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';`
2. Add *TranslateService* to providers in *TestBed* configuration:
   `providers: [ TranslateService ]`

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a better approach to do so:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    RouterTestingModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useClass: TranslateFakeLoader
      }
    }),
    HttpClientTestingModule
  ],
  declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
})
.compileComponents();
}));
```

Comment: It'd help to state what line(s) in your code chunk is the solution, along some written explanation. See, I faced this issue almost 3 years ago, and my brain cache has been cleared since.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you'are adding

```
{ Provide: TranslationService, useValue: translateServiceStub }
```

in providers

Comment: I will have to try that some day when I get the time for it.