# NullInjectorError: No provider for translate service

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, ngx-translate

I'm developing an app in Cordova + angular 8 and want add different idioms in the app , so I decided to install this library , I follow the instructions that I see in a video , but when I try to launch the app, I have an error in the library code so I change the library version, finally other version works but the app keep loading and don't works well , so I create a new project with nothing more than what comes by default in an angular project, that is to say something similar to a "*hello world*" and add that library and have the same problem and in the local server appears that error :

[image: Error screenshot]

I have tried to solve it searching for this error in Google. I have checked all this solutions, but no one is working:

-https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/68

-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132590/error-in-ngx-translate-core-error-ts1086-an-accessor-cannot-be-declared-in-a

-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61678136/test-no-provider-for-translateservice

As I have commented I have followed several videos to realize this, from this video is where I finally got my code :

-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_tpfsrseJ8

Comment: Can you update your question with your `app.module`

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Is this a problem or are you recommending the video? _As I have commented I have followed several videos to realize this, from this video is where I finally got my code : {{link}}_

Answer (score 1):

Please add "TranslateModule.forRoot()" in your import array of app.module.ts,

if not works, then please share the code of app.module.ts.

Comment: that was the error, thank you for responding so quickly and sorry for the inconvenience. i think now is solved thank you